# Communication between portlet and servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, portlet

Hi i have written a portlet which generates a report in pdf format but my requirement is to provide the download option for the user to download that pdf, i am using servlet to download the file but i am not able to pass the information from portlet to servlet.

please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should generate the PDF-report in the servlet itself. Othervise you probably need to use some temporary directory to store the pdf and download it from there in the servlet.